# What's on Joe's desk at 10:38 am?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Joe's morning at the advertising agency:

> **10:30 am**: Joe looks on his empty desktop and realizes he has no cigarettes. He asks his coworkers to get him some cigarettes from the
>   interns.
>
> **10:31 am**: Joe has a single cigarette on his desk.
>
> **10:32 am**: Joe has 2 cigarettes on his desk.
>
> **10:33 am**: Joe has 3 cigarettes on his desk, so he starts smoking.
>
> **10:34 am**: Joe has a single cigarette on his desk, and now has an ashtray.
>
> **10:35 am**: Joe has no more cigarettes on his desk, but keeps the ashtray for later.
>
> **10:36 am**: Joe's desktop is still empty, except for a single cigarette and the ashtray.

**What's on Joe's desk at 10:38 am, and why?**

Comment: I bet it's cancer.

Comment: A pink slip for smoking at his desk.  Take that stuff outside, Joe!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joe (not me) has three cigarettes next to his ashtray.

The pattern is the Roman numerals representing the minutes past 10:30 AM. The cigarettes on the desk represent I's, and the ashtray stands for a V.

At 10:40 he might have a can of soda on his desk and taken the ashtray off, to represent an X.

Comment: While the mechanism was cute and the puzzle was solved quickly, I think the puzzle would be improved by stronger theming. The "aha" of Roman numerals is unconnected to "smoking" and "advertising agency" and "Joe". Cigarettes do look like I's, but astrays don't look like V's, but there's probably another object that looks or starts with "V". The 10:30 doesn't matter and points in the wrong direction of clock hands. Joe could instead have has the things at 1pm, 2pm, etc.

Comment: While I sympathize with your not wanting your posts changed (I regularly revert edits to my answers which only add spoilers), in this case it's an important qualifier to the problem. Unless you edit it yourself, it's likely that your question will continue garnering a smattering of downvotes for having an ambiguous representation of the problem.

Comment: Although for that matter, upon further reflection, it would more elegantly be 10:34 when the cigarette is in the ashtray, not 10:36, so that items that are directly on the table represent items that are added together.

Comment: Most comments purged, as they were obsolete / noise. Please notify me of any comments that should be undeleted. (@JLee - please try to maintain a constructive tone.)